# Tools for receiving build notifications in Skype group chat

Tags: build-process, notifications, skype

My team uses skype group chat, and I would love to have a tool that could post notifications to our group chat.

I would like to avoid relying on an RSS feed, but it may come down to that.  But even that it seems hard to find -- there seems to have been a tool called Anothr that perhaps went out of existence.

I would also prefer to not have a 3rd party (outside of Skype) that receives the messages -- e.g. I don't want a bot that is hosted by a third party on a server somewhere, with their bot sitting in our group chat.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746081/how-can-i-alert-skype-chatrooms-with-jenkins-build-status/6746084#6746084

Answer (score 0):

You did not state what kind of build server you use.
If you are happy with Jenkins, there is a plugin for that:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Skype+Plugin

I did not check whether it can send groupchat messages, though.