# How can I alert Skype chatrooms with Jenkins build status?

Tags: api, jenkins, skype

Our company uses Skype for communications, and I'd like to be able to send alerts to Skype chatrooms when a Jenkins build fails (and when it recovers too).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've done this using the [Skype Public API](http://developer.skype.com/accessories)

What I did was write a Perl script which uses the [SkypeAPI](http://search.cpan.org/~laomoi/SkypeAPI-0.08/lib/SkypeAPI.pm) CPAN module to handle the communications with Skype. It's a little clunky, as the script needs to run on a desktop which is running Skype. I run it on my own desktop which is always on anyway, but this does mean the bot appears to be 'me' to the rest of our team.

The end result is fantastic - whenever a jenkins build changes state, the bot sends a message to any Skype chats which have registered an interest by typing *alert. Additionally, any developer can see and share the latest build status by typing *jenkins

### Step 1 - Extending the SkypeAPI module

Now, the SkypeAPI module is pretty basic. It has a message loop in the listen() method which checks for new events from the Skype client, and sleeps for a moment if there none.

I wanted my script to hook into this loop so that I could have my bot periodically check Jenkins RSS feed, so I made the following modifications to SkypeAPI.pm after I had installed it with the ActiveState package manager:

I declared new property 'idler' along with the existing properties...

```
__PACKAGE__->mk_accessors(
  qw/api handler_list stop_listen idler/
);
```

I added a method to set an 'idler' callback which the module will call instead of sleeping

```
sub register_idler {
    my $self = shift;
    my $ref_sub = shift;
    $self->idler($ref_sub);
}
```

Finally I modified the message loop to call the idler if set

```
sub listen {
    my $self = shift;

    my $idler=$self->idler();

    $self->stop_listen(0);
    while (!$self->stop_listen) {
        my $message;
        {
            lock @message_list;
            $message = shift @message_list;
        }
        if (not defined $message) {
            if ($idler)
            {
                $self->idler->($self);
            }
            else
            {
                sleep 0.1;             
            }
            next;
        }
        for my $id (sort keys %{$self->handler_list}) {
            $self->handler_list->{$id}->($self, $message);
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 2 - write a robot script

Now the module is a little more capable, it's just a matter of writing a script to act as a bot. Here's mine - I've made a few edits from my original as it contained other irrelevant functionality, but it should give you a starting point.

All of the dependant modules can be installed with the ActiveState package manager.

```
use strict;
use SkypeAPI;
use LWP::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use dirtyRSS;
use Time::Local 'timegm';
use Math::Round;
use Storable;

#CHANGE THIS - where to get jenkins status from
my $jenkinsRss='http://username:password@jenkins.example.com/rssLatest';

my %commands=(
    'jenkins'   =>\&cmdJenkins,
    'alert'     =>\&cmdAlert,
    'noalert'   =>\&cmdNoAlert,
    'help'      =>\&cmdHelp,
);

my $helpMessage=<<HELP;
Who asked for help? Here's all the other special commands I know...

  *jenkins - show status of our platform tests
  *alert - add this room to get automatic notification of build status
  *noalert - cancel notifcations
  *help - displays this message
HELP


#status for jenkins tracking
my %builds;
my $lastJenkinsCheck=0;
my $alertRoomsFile='alert.rooms';
my $alertRooms={};

#store jenkins state
checkJenkins();

#because that was our first fetch, we'll have flagged everything as changed
#but it hasn't really, so we reset those flags
resetJenkinsChangeFlags();

#remember rooms we're supposed to alert
loadAlertRooms();

#attach to skype and enter message loop
my $skype = SkypeAPI->new();
my $attached=$skype->attach();
$skype->register_handler(\&onEvent);
$skype->register_idler(\&onIdle);
$skype->listen();

exit;

#here are the command handlers
sub cmdJenkins
{
    my ($chatId, $args)=@_;

    my $message="";
    foreach my $build (keys(%builds))
    {
        $message.=formatBuildMessage($build)."\n";

        #reset changed flag - we've just show the status
        $builds{$build}->{'changed'}=0;
    }

    chatmessage($chatId, $message);
}

sub cmdAlert
{
    my ($chatId, $args)=@_;
    addChatroomToAlerts($chatId,1);
}

sub cmdNoAlert
{
    my ($chatId, $args)=@_;
    addChatroomToAlerts($chatId,0);
}

sub cmdHelp
{
    my ($chatId, $args)=@_;
    chatmessage($chatId, $helpMessage);
}






#simple helper to transmit a message to a specific chatroom
sub chatmessage
{
    my ($chatId, $message)=@_;
    my $commandstr="CHATMESSAGE $chatId $message";
    my $command = $skype->create_command( { string => $commandstr}  );
    $skype->send_command($command);
}


#refreshes our copy of jenkins state, and will flag any builds
#which have changed state since the last check
sub checkJenkins{

    my $xml = get($jenkinsRss);
    my $tree = parse($xml);
    my $items=$tree->{'channel'}->[0]->{'item'};

    foreach my $item (@{$items})
    {
        my $title=$item->{'title'};
        my $link=$item->{'link'};
        my $built=$item->{'lastbuilddate'};

        #print Dumper($item);

        if ($title=~m/^(.*?) #(\d+)\s*(.*)$/)
        {
            my $build=$1;
            my $buildnumber=$2;
            my $status=$3;
            #print "$build\n$buildnumber\n$status\n$link\n$built\n\n";    

            #build in progress, ignore

            if (!exists($builds{$build}))
            {
                $builds{$build}={};
                $builds{$build}->{'status'}='';
                $builds{$build}->{'changed'}=0;
            }

            $builds{$build}->{'name'}=$build;

            if ($status eq '(?)')
            {
                $builds{$build}->{'in_progress'}=1;
                next; #don't update until complete
            }
            else
            {
                $builds{$build}->{'in_progress'}=0;
            }

            #is this status different to last status?
            if ($builds{$build}->{'status'} ne $status)
            {
                $builds{$build}->{'changed'}=1;
            }

            $builds{$build}->{'status'}=$status;
            $builds{$build}->{'build_number'}=$buildnumber;
            $builds{$build}->{'link'}=$link;
            $builds{$build}->{'built'}=$built;

        }
    }
    #print Dumper(\%builds);


}

#generates a string suitable for displaying build status in skype
sub formatBuildMessage
{
    my ($build)=@_;
    my $status=$builds{$build}->{'status'};

    my $smiley=":)";
    if ($status=~m/broken/)
    {
        $smiley="(devil)";

    }
    elsif ($status=~m/\?/)
    {
         #this means the build is being retested, we should skip it
         $smiley=":|";
    }

    my $message='';

    if ($builds{$build}->{'in_progress'})
    {
       $message=":| $build - rebuild in progress..."
    }
    else
    {

        my ($y,$mon,$d,$h,$m,$s) = $builds{$build}->{'built'} =~ m/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)Z/;
        my $time = timegm($s,$m,$h,$d,$mon-1,$y);
        my $age=time()-$time;

        my $mins=round($age/60);
        my $hrs=round($age/3600);
        my $days=round($age/86400);

        my $niceage;
        if ($mins<=2)
        {
            $niceage="a few moments ago";
        }
        elsif ($mins<120)
        {
             $niceage="$mins minutes ago";
        }
        elsif ($hrs<48)
        {
             $niceage="$hrs hours ago";
        }
        else
        {
            $niceage="$days days ago";
        }

        $message="$smiley $build last built $niceage $status";
    }
    return $message;
}

#forget any changes we've flagged
sub resetJenkinsChangeFlags
{
   foreach my $build (keys(%builds))
   {
       $builds{$build}->{'changed'}=0;
   }
}

#checks for builds which have changed state. Can be called
#often, it will only kick in if 60 seconds have elapsed since
#last check
sub checkForJenkinsChanges
{
    my $now=time();
    if (($now-$lastJenkinsCheck) < 60)
    {
        #no need, we fetched it recently
        return;
    }

    checkJenkins();

    my $message='';

    foreach my $build (keys(%builds))
    {
        if ($builds{$build}->{'changed'})
        {
            $builds{$build}->{'changed'}=0;
            $message.=formatBuildMessage($build)."\n";
        }

    }

    if (length($message))
    {
        foreach my $chatId (keys(%$alertRooms))
        {
            chatmessage($chatId, $message);
        }
    }

    $lastJenkinsCheck=$now;
}

#adds or removes a room from the alerts
sub addChatroomToAlerts
{
    my($chatId, $add)=@_;
    if ($add)
    {
        if (exists($alertRooms->{$chatId}))
        {
            chatmessage($chatId, "/me says this room is already getting alerts");
        }
        else
        {
            $alertRooms->{$chatId}=1;
            chatmessage($chatId, "/me added this chatroom to jenkins alerts");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        delete($alertRooms->{$chatId});
        chatmessage($chatId, "/me removed this chatroom from jenkins alerts");
    }

    store $alertRooms, $alertRoomsFile;
}   

sub loadAlertRooms
{
    if (-e  $alertRoomsFile)
    {
        $alertRooms = retrieve( $alertRoomsFile);
    }
}


# Skype event handler
sub onEvent {
    my $skype = shift;
    my $msg = shift;
    #my $command = $skype->create_command( { string => "GET USERSTATUS"}  );
    #print $skype->send_command($command) , "\n";

    #print "handler: $msg\n";

    #an inbound chat message is either
    #MESSAGE 13021257 STATUS RECEIVED (from others)
    #MESSAGE 13021257 STATUS SENT (from us)

    if ($msg =~ m/MESSAGE (\d+) STATUS (SEND|RECEIVED)/)
    {
        my $msgId=$1;

        #get message body
        my $commandstr="GET CHATMESSAGE $msgId BODY";
        my $command = $skype->create_command( { string => $commandstr}  );
        my $output=$skype->send_command($command);


        #if its a message for us...
        if ($output =~ m/MESSAGE $msgId BODY \*([^\s]*)\s*(.*)/i)
        {
            my $botcmd=$1;
            my $botargs=$2;

            $commandstr="GET CHATMESSAGE $msgId CHATNAME";
            $command = $skype->create_command( { string => $commandstr}  );
            $output=$skype->send_command($command);

            if ($output =~ m/MESSAGE $msgId CHATNAME (.*)/)
            {
                my $chatId=$1;
                if (exists($commands{$botcmd}))
                {
                    $commands{$botcmd}->($chatId, $botargs);
                }
                else
                {
                    chatmessage($chatId, "/me suggests trying *help as the robot didn't understand *$botcmd");
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}



#skype idle handler
#Note - SkypeAPI.pm was modified to support this
sub onIdle {
    my $skype = shift;
    checkForJenkinsChanges();
    sleep 0.1;             
}
```

### Step 3 - Run the bot

If you've saved this as robot.pl, just open a console window and `perl robot.pl` should get it running. Skype will ask you if perl.exe should be allowed to communicate with it, and once you confirm that, you're good to go!

Go into a team chatroom and type `*jenkins` for an summary of latest builds, and register the room for alerts of build changes with `*alert`

Perfect :)

Comment: Since I wrote this post I added a nice *blame command you use to get a good summary of who might be blame for a build breakage. If enough people are interested I'll clean it up and stick on github...

Comment: @PaulDixon I'm interested in the github project if you can set one up

Comment: This was 6 years ago, and I'm not using this anymore. I don't know if it would still work, but I'll see if I can dig it up...

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer provided above is a working solution, I think that is a bit old and no tools were available at the time the question was asked. There is a plugin available for Jenkins to integrate with skype:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Skype+Plugin

This plugin can be used to send notification to a particular user or a group chat. I've been using it for a while and it works great. I primarily use linux servers for my Jenkins servers and I have a dedicated windows server with skype installed and logged in as a bot user. The only configuration needed for running skype in a slave is that it requires a label called "skype". With this label Jenkins will detect the slave and route skype notification to that slave.

Answer (score 0):

One can use Sevabot (https://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/) project to setup a HTTP based interface for Skype and then use [Jenkin's Notification Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin):

Example: https://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/jenkins.html